# How in Svelte call child function when it is inside IF statement

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

How in svelte bind function from child component, when child component is inside IF statement and is not visible on init? Eg. parent component, child exports childExportedFunc()

```
<script>
import Child from './Child.svelte'

let childFunction;
let childIsVisible = false;

const visibleChild = () => {
    childIsVisible = true;
    childFunction();
}
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click={visibleChild}>visible</button>
    {#if childIsVisible}
        <Child bind:childExportedFunc={childFunction}
    {/if}
</main>
```

As I understand it raises exception as childExportedFunc() is not binded yet when it is called, because svelte binds on render and this component is not rendered yet. Is there any way to force bind?

Comment: What do you need that for? Using component exported functions is fairly uncommon.

Comment: Well, in this particular case the flow is that child component works like flashmessage, but every time is is shown message it shows must be rerendered: it contains some random hash and also message itself also depends on that hash. To make it reusable it exposes method to re-render message.

Comment: Maybe that could also be done using props and `onMount`, not sure. Possibly with a reactive statement that updates when the input prop changes, so no function call is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the DOM/binding to update [using `tick`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#tick):

```js
const visibleChild = async () => {
    childIsVisible = true;
    await tick();
    childFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.